# Recover Minecraft Pi world after Accidental system shutdown

Tags: pi-2, minecraft, games

While playing the Minecraft Pi on my Raspberry Pi 2B, accidentally the system went off, and when I log on again I'm only able to see the "create world" button. I can't find my last saved world. Is there any way to recover my last saved world?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried looking into the world saves folder in the file system ?

Comment: Sorry for late reply, where can i found that folder?

Comment: Should be under `~/minecraft/games/com.mojang/minecraftWorlds/`

Answer (score 2):

Note: The question asks about Minecraft Pi, which apparently isn't just Minecraft on a Raspberry Pi.

Minecraft must be told to `/save` or `/quit` so that it can properly shutdown and save.  If you do not properly save the changes to disk, it is unlikely you will be able to recover your world or the changes you made.

Using the Minecraft console, you can issue `/save` periodically to make saves to prevent this issue.  Alternatively, you can give your account admin/moderator privileges and issue this command from your client.  If you put your Minecraft console on a pipe, you can pipe in commands via `cron`:

```bsh
#One-time setup.
cd minecraft-1.14
mkfifo serverpipe
```

```bsh
# Starting the server each time
tmux
cd minecraft-1.14
tail -f serverpipe | java -Xms1G -Xmx5G -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+UseParNewGC -jar minecraft_server.1.14.jar nogui
```

```bsh
# Running a command and testing
echo "/say Hello, world" > serverpipe
echo "/save" > serverpipe
```

```bsh
# Cron entry to save every hour
crontab -e

0 * * * * /bin/echo "/save" /full/path/to/minecraft-1.14/serverpipe
```

Be warned that if you save, there is no backup of previous saves.  This is most important if your server does not use a whitelist, or there is any reason you could be "griefed".  If the server automatically saves every hour, it will save, even if someone pours lava all over the world.

Comment: Bookmarking this as the answer looks pretty handy for Minecraft Java Edition. However, note the OP is asking about Minecraft Pi Edition 0.1.1 (~Pocket Edition 0.6.1) which does not support these commands.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying.  I didn't realize this was a specific version, vs Minecraft Java on a Pi.